# 'python manage.py collectstatic' is still collecting static to C drive instead of s3 bucket, am I missing something?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3, django-staticfiles

I am trying to use s3 bucket with django (I have done this like twice before) but this time, after installing boto3 and django-storages and assigning correct values to necessary variables in settings.py, `python manage.py collectstatic` is still collecting static files to a local directory on my computer instead of s3 bucket. Below is my settings.py...

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "storages",
]

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "*****"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "******"
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "****"
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = "%s.s3.amazonaws.com" % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {"CacheControl": "max-age=86400"}
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "build/static", #this is the correct path by the way!
]

STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

**terminal**

```
(env) C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\project> python manage.py collectstatic

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\project\staticfiles

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?
```

According to all tutorials and my expectation, `collectstatic` is supposed to be collecting my static files into my s3 bucket.. Am I missing something??

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you sure `STATICFILES_STORAGE` is not being overidden somewhere else (in other env file maybe)?

Comment: Yes..yes.. this is it! I have already installed and started using  `django-heroku` and I forget to set it's `staticfiles=False` . Thank you Saad!

Comment: Cool, glad that this could help you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to have define my own subclass of S3Boto3Storage and use that

```py
# ./storage_backends.py - lives in the same dir as the config file.

from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

from django.conf import settings


class StaticRootS3BotoStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.STATIC_DIRECTORY
```

Then

```py
# config.py

STATIC_DIRECTORY = BASE_DIR + "/build/static" # You will need to change this to your path
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'config.settings.storage_backends.StaticRootS3BotoStorage' # you also need to change this to the path to the file we created above.

STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATIC_DIRECTORY)
```

Now you can override methods for debugging and see where the problem might be.