# Amazon S3 + Cloudfront with Django - Access error in serving static files (400 - Bad Request authorization mechanism not supported)

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-cloudfront, django-storage

I'm struggling with an issue I'm encountering while testing my Django project's production environment, and more especially with my static (and media) content by the use of S3 + Cloudfront.

As I'm developing on Django, I make use of the latest version of django-storage.
The problem is that in spite of loading all the environment variables in my **settings.py** file (more details below), my website is still always trying to load the static/media content using the S3 direct URLs of the form *https://bucket_name.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/static/filename*.

The static content cannot be loaded using these URLs and I get the following error : *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)*.
When I try to access these URLs in my browser I get the following message : **The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256**
This error seems quite weird to me as I specified the signature version in my settings file (perhaps I miss something?).

The other point is that I want to rely on Cloudfront as first layer so that my files get a unique path of the form "https://xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/static/..." So I defined a Cloudfront distribution with OAI and Bucket policy configured.
But I still don't get my files served through this URL and get the same problem as before (without Cloudfront).

For info, if I manually replace the first part of static files URLs by the Cloudfront URI (without even touching to the arguments (which are respectively *AWSAccessKeyId*, *Signature* and *Expiry*) the access is working.

Here is my **settings.py** file parameters:

```
    
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "myAccessKeyID"
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "myAWSAccessKey"
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "my_bucket_name"

    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = "xxxxxx.cloudfront.net"

    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {    
        'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'
    }
    
    AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
    AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'eu-west-3'
 
    STATIC_LOCATION = 'static'

    STATIC_ROOT = '/%s/' % STATIC_LOCATION
    STATIC_URL='https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATIC_LOCATION)
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
    

    PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
    MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
    MEDIA_ROOT = '/%s/' % MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
    MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION)
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

I browsed on the internet to find posts on similar issues, and I implemented the different solution suggested like explicitely defining the variables **AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION** and **AWS_S3_REGION_NAME** ('eu-west-3' here as my bucket is in Paris) or make the origin domain name very explicit with its region in the Cloudfront distribution parameters. Unfortunately, this didn't work for me so far.

I also wiped my browser cache and tried again with new buckets/Cloudfront distribution without more success...

At this stage, I made my bucket publicly accessible. The collectstatic method is working to populate the bucket. The cloudfront distribution seems ok as I can manually get access to my bucket using it when I 're-construct' the URL. Finally, the IAM user has S3FullAccess as well as CloudfrontFullAccess rights (for testing purpose). But perhaps I miss an important setting on AWS side...

Many thanks in advance for your help that would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit 15th June :**

Following @Trent advice, I defined the following custom storage class as STATICFILES_STORAGE. Variables seem to be correctly imported (I print them in the python console before collectstatic) but I still get the same issue.

In my **settings.py** file :

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'myproject.storage_backends.StaticStorage' 
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myproject.storage_backends.PublicMediaStorage'
```

Here is the code of my custom storage class **storage_backends.py**:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):

    location = 'static'
    custom_domain = "xxxxxx.cloudfront.net"    
    signature_version = "s3v4"
    region = "eu-west-3"
    default_acl = "public-read"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['custom_domain'] = custom_domain
        kwargs['signature_version'] = signature_version
        kwargs['region_name'] = region
        
        super(StaticStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    
class PublicMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):

    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['custom_domain'] = "xxxxxx.cloudfront.net"    
        kwargs['signature_version'] = "s3v4"
    
        super(PublicMediaStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: See this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/67913759/1389057

Comment: Hi @Trent and thanks for your answer. I followed your link and defined a custom S3Boto3Storage class taken then as reference for STATICFILES_STORAGE. I checked that variables were correctly imported and it seems to be the case. Unfortunately, same issue (please see edits in post). Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't have any NGINX location directives overriding /static/ do you?